# Google Pay PaymentMethodTokenRecipient function implementation in Golang

Tags: go, google-pay, tink

I am trying to implement Google Pay decryption method as mentioned.

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#decrypt-token

It mentions to use `tink` library with the example of Java (PaymentMethodTokenRecipient) but I'm unable to duplicate it for Golang.

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally familiar with the library, but have a look at [Tink](https://github.com/google/tink/tree/master/go).

There's a [decrypt method](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/6ad153edf2f5f954c5a4e99ac94f77fe345ae842/go/hybrid/hybrid_decrypt_factory.go#L59) that may do what you are after, and a [cli](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/tools/testing/go/hybrid_decrypt_cli.go) that may help with how to use it: https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/tools/testing/go/hybrid_decrypt_cli.go